# How to use numpy.arange with two other arrays as the start and stop parameter?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I want to build a 2D-array where the first dimension has the same length as two other arrays and the second dimension is an array created by numpy.arange and based on every element of the other two arrays, where one array defines the start parameter and the second array defines the stop parameter-1.

Let me give an example:

```
arr_1 = array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
arr_2 = array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

I'm trying to create a resulting array like this:

```
res_arr = array([[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6]])
```

Can this be done with numpy ?

Comment: Did you try it with arange? Also, it won't have your wanted output. `np.arange(0,0)` will have an empty array as output, not `[0]`, because the stop is not included.

Comment: That's why I said stop parameter -1. So np.arange(0, 0+1). But ofcourse that's not working on this specific problem. That's why I asked.

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious loop?  You want a list of arrays of differing lengths.  Even with a `np.array` wrapper `res_arr` will not be 2d!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using zip and list comprehension

```
res_arr = [np.arange(start, stop + 1) for start, stop in zip(arr_1, arr_2)]
```